# purpose of android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0"

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I forgot to change the `versionCode` in manifest file. Now, I have one query along with `versionCode`, `versionName` has to be changed or not?

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.sb.jw" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest file:
Two properties are extremely important:

1. versionCode = "..."
2. versionName = "..."
3. versionCode is a unique number which is assigned to the application which is connected with the certificate used to .apk in release mode.
4. versionName is for showing the version name. It can be **same** for every release but versionCode should be *unique* for every release.